# Ошибка в коде на проверяющей системе codeforces Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, алгоритм

У меня есть прога которая находит минимум каждой строки и добавляет его в список.
Локально у меня все работает, но на проверяющей системе codeforces выдает ошибку.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "program.pys3", line 1, in <module>
    n = int(input()) 
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
```

вот сам код

```
n = int(input()) 
a = []
b = []
for i in range(n):
    a.append([str(j) for j in input().split()])
for i in range(len(a)):
    for j in range(1):
        if len(a[i][0]) == 1:
            b.append(a[i][0])
        else:
            for v in range(len(a[i][0])):
                l = min(a[i][0][j], a[i][0][j+1])
                a[i][0] = a[i][0][:j] + l + a[i][0][j+1:]
                a[i][0] = a[i][0][:j+1] + l + a[i][0][j+2:]
            b.append(l)
t_str = ''.join(map(str, b))
print(t_str)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Что такое "находит минимум каждой строки"? Приведите примеры входных и выходных данных

Comment: Дайте ссылку на задачу раз уж указали Codeforces. Либо приведите здесь условие. И расскажите какая ошибка возникает.

Comment: Условие лучше вставить текстом, так его можно скопировать. Вообще, никогда и нигде не выкладывайте текст картинкой.

Answer (score 1):

Вы когда у себя проверяете - число n с клавиатуры вводите? Или из файла?

Может быть, дело в том, что на проверяющей системе некому ввести число?

Обычно указывают имя файла `input.txt`, из которого вводятся значения в программу. У вас нигде этого файла не указано. Поэтому и ошибка в первой же строке: `Хозяин, я файл найти не могу! не знаю, какой искать!`

Comment: n вводится с клавиатуры

Comment: Значит, надо проситать руководство по тестирующей системе на Codeforces, там должен быть пример для Вашего языка и ввода данных из файла input.txt. И переделать ввод данных так же, как в этом примере

Comment: На codeforces используется стандартный ввод/вывод, т.ч. проблема не в этом.